# Does zone.js have something to do with css not rendering?

Tags: css, angular, zone.js

I have a print preview CSS and it is all working in my current location. I've tested it in different browsers and computers and they're all working fine. But when viewed in Japan location, CSS doesn't work specifically on the `<table>`.

Warnings were seen in their browser console that has something to do with zone.js but isn't seen in the developer's location therefore we cannot see what really is the problem:
[image]

Question: Does zone.js has something to do with css not rendering in Japan location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zone.js` shown in the far right in the screenshot is a red herring. Zone.js wraps all the asynchronous APIs of the browser, including `requestAnimationFrame()`.

These lines with the pale yellow background are warnings that Chrome logs as performance hints that your code is slower than ideal. They are nothing to do with CSS.

Chrome is showing these warnings as coming from `zone.js` because that is where the custom implementation of `requestAnimationFrame()` is.

So I don't know why it's not working in Japan, but you can rule out Zone.js as the cause.

Comment: I've ruled out Zone.js but the css is still not working. Guess they aren't connected at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Zone.js` has nothing to do with `CSS` rendering. It is a library to handle JavaScript asynchronous operations.

Comment: but loading css from angular is a js cli and angular can create css as js, so zone might be affecting css as well?